# How can i stop multiple create runOnUiThread() when activity finish()

Tags: android, android-runonuithread

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
    channelAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    stopActivityIndicator();
    setChannel(0);
    }
});
```

i have added this code in my activity and when back press finish activity then my main activity is block all User Interface, i don't know why this happen.

Comment: Why are you calling notifyDataSetChanged in onBackPress? What is the use case? Are you performing any heavy operations in runOnUIThread block ?

Comment: i am not calling notifyDataSetChanged in onBackPress. i calling notifyDataSetChanged in my runOnUiThread() as above on my activity onBackPress i just write finish(),

Comment: it will be helpful to see a error stacktrace, please provide...

Comment: you should call this via handler and a global runnable. Then you can call yourHandler.removeCallbacks(yourRunnable). Then you should be able to exit the app without blocking all...

Comment: There is no any error display on stacktrace, on my back activity is open and i can't interact with the User interface.

Comment: i test my app using creating handler and runnable object as globally and on backpress removeCallbacks(handler). then app is crash, the error is look like this - Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare(),   Thanks for the response